# TableModelEvent and passing data to a controller class and a database

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

Apologies if this is basic, or I've missed something, but I'm self taught and not too sure of best practices for doing this.

I'm trying to pass data that's changed in my JTable (the user editing a cell manually which calls setValueAt() in the TableModel), to a Controller:

```
@Override
public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col){
    Person person = data.get(row); // Data is a simple arraylist underlying the model
    switch(col){
        case 1 : person.setTitle((String)value);break;
        case 2 : person.setFName((String)value);break;
        case 3 : person.setMName((String)value);break;
        case 4 : person.setSName((String)value);break;
    }
    this.fireTableCellUpdated(row,col);
}
```

So I've set a TableModelListener in the JTable using a setter and an abstract class from the Controller:

```
class PersonTable extends JTable{
    private PersonTableModel pTableModel;
    private TableModelListener tml;

    public PersonTable(){
        pTableModel = new PersonTableModel();
        setModel(pTableModel);

        setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    }

    public void setTableModelListener(TableModelListener tml){
        pTableModel.add(tml);
    }
}
```

Setting the ModelListener from the Controller class:

```
    personTable.setTableModelListener(new TableModelListener(){
        @Override
        public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
            Person p = ((PersonTableModel)e.getSource()).getPerson(e.getFirstRow());
            switch(e.getType()){
                case TableModelEvent.UPDATE : model.updatePerson(p.getId(), e.getColumn()); // un-written method 
            }
        }
    });
```

I'm now focusing on that switch statement. I've access to the Object from the changed row, and the column index that was altered in that row. I've yet to write the `updatePerson(int, int)` method and the resulting SQL, but this seems brittle to me. I can already tell that I'm going to have problems as my JTable doesn't contain every column that the database does - so the column number won't correspond.

I think it's possible for me to add all my database columns to my TableModel, and then remove them from the JTable, which sounds like it might fix the issue, but I'd rather get more information from the TableModelEvent. Like header information that I could use in a switch and then SQL WHERE clause.

Sorry if this isn't clear enough. I've a SSCCE for this, but with the TableModel, Table, and Person class it's unfortunately not that small. But I can post any class needed. Would appreciate any advice!

Comment: `so the column number won't correspond.` - I would say the column number is irrelevant. All you need is the row number. Then you get the data from the TableModel and create your SQL statement to update whatever data you store in the model. So I guess I'm suggestion you update all the data in the row no matter which column was changed.

Comment: If you really only want to update a single column in the database, then you can just get the column name from the table header. Then you will need to map this to the column name of your database.

Comment: thanks. yeah thinking about it i suppose it's probably not worth the effort. does my approach look relatively sensible (as far as you can tell) other than that? it's hard to know when trying to use examples from books that aren't quite a 1:1 fit.

Comment: i know that there isn't a real need to use a controller, but it's made me a lot more comfortable with listeners (which is why i initially did it this way)